# How to find all unique datatypes in a DataFrame column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[int(1),2,3],[int(5),6,'a'],[0.1,4,True]], columns = list("abc"))
df
   a    b  c
0  1.0  2  3
1  5.0  6  a
2  0.1  4  True
```

(side question: why doesn't declaring `int` do anything?)

Now, `df.dtypes` returns

```
a    float64
b      int64
c     object
dtype: object
```

But is it possible to actually list all the different data types in one column?

Like

```
a    int64, float64
b    int64
c    int64, str, bool
```

Comment: @jpp, ah, prefect. I couldn't find that exact question on SO for some reason. Prolly cuz I didn't use the word "subtypes". Thank you! Tho I'm not just looking for objects, so it might be a little different. Like `include=[df[c].dtype for c in df.columns]`

Comment: I would have a better solution, but can not anwser direclty (thanks stackoverflow), sorry man.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.applymap(type)` to get back a dataframe with the the types of individual values in the original dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],[5, 6, 'a'],[0.1, 4, True]], columns = list("abc"))

print(df.applymap(type))
```

Outputs

```
                 a              b               c
0  <class 'float'>  <class 'int'>   <class 'int'>
1  <class 'float'>  <class 'int'>   <class 'str'>
2  <class 'float'>  <class 'int'>  <class 'bool'>
```

> side question: why doesn't declaring `int` do anything?)

There is no such thing as "declaring" in Python. `int(1)` does (almost) nothing different than `1`. Column `a` shows as `float64` because the last element is `0.1`. This causes `pandas` to convert `1` and `5` to `float` (since `0.1` can not be converted to `int`).

Comment: that works :) is there a one-liner to do `.unique()` on each column?

Comment: @Raksha This should be a separate question with its own expected input and output

Comment: how do you mean? That was the question >.> ... and the expected outcome only lists unique results, not one for each entry <.<

Comment: @Raksha the original question is about types, it does not mention uniqueness in any way.

Comment: it was implied by the presented outcome XD